# Backtracking during debugging in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, breakpoints

Let's say I have function A(//Code: To Catch Some Error) in a class and that function A() is being called in 100 different pages.

1. I have put one breakpoint at that function A().
2. When I run the solution in the visual studio, this breakpoint is being hit.

Q: Is there any way to find from which page did this function A() was called before hitting the breakpoint?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best option is looking at the call stack. When you hit a breakpoint Visual Studio will by default include Call Stack window among the windows that appear below your main code window. You will see a list of nested function calls that took you to the breakpoint. Double-clicking on any of the functions should open it in the debugger, assuming you have the source code for it (some of them will be system functions).